# Execute event at an exact time in cypress

Tags: cypress

I want my cypress test script to click a button as soon as the current time is past 20:00 UTC

I have a cron job on my server which triggers the e2e flow a few minutes before 20:00

So far so good, the test is being executed, I have a loop checking the time and waiting until 20:00 is reached, then hit the button and continue the test

```
for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
   currentHour = (new Date()).getUTCHours();
   if(currentHour == 20)
   {
      cy.get(......).click();
      break;
   }
   cy.wait(500);
}
```

But the way I understand cypress is built, `new Date()` always stays the same because all javascript is executed right away, so it contains the timestamp of test initialization...

I've been trying some stuff with `cy.task`, you can return a new date there but you can't use `await` to wait for that correct date retrieval since it doesn't return an acutal promise; more something from cypress itself

What else can I try? It seems an easy test but so hard to get exactly what I want

Comment: What behavior are you testing that is time-specific to 20:00. Why not mock that behavior so that you can run that test more frequently than only after 20:00?

Comment: The application (server) only allows certain actions in a very small timewindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couln't use clock as the time I am targetting is defined on server; the application only allows certain actions in a very small timeframe.

Found a solution though with the very use full [Cypress wait until plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until)

I created a task to get the actual date

**cypress.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on('task', {
        getCurrentHour() {
          const date = new Date();
          console.log(date + ' - ' + 'Checking current hour: ' + date.getUTCHours())
          return date.getUTCHours();
        }
      })
    },
  },
});
```

**spec.cy.ts**

```
cy.waitUntil(() => cy.task("getCurrentHour").then(hour => hour === targetUTCHour), {timeout: 180000, // waits up to 2000 ms, default to 5000
    interval: 1000});
    // Execute code here
);
```

Answer (score 2):

To make Cypress stay on the same date, you need to use [cy.clock()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock).

This command can be used to set the system to an exact date and time, but not allow the time to move forward until you issue the `cy.tick()` command.

It's hard to see what you are expecting to test, but this is how your test might look

```js
cy.clock(new Date(2023, 2, 14, 19, 59, 30))
cy.visit('/')

// test something before the deadline

cy.tick(30_000)
cy.get(......).click()

// test something after the deadline
```